# Array doesn't get calculated

Tags: c

Good day , i'm having this issue with the following C code . I'm trying to perform this operation, the sum of (each entered number has to be multiplied by its generated one) . What am I missing ?

i'm getting this error : incompatible types when assigning to type 'float *' from type 'float' .
Any help will be welcomed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
application();

return 0;
}


void application(void)
{
int input = 0;
float number[10];
float total =0;
float *ptr;
float generatedNum; 

srand(time(NULL));


for(input; input<11; input++)
{   
generatedNum = 2 *(float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX - 1;


printf("\n\n\t\tEnter number %d : ", input);
scanf("%f", &number[input]);
ptr = number * generatedNum;

printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tMachine Value: %.1f", generatedNum);

}

for(input; input<11; input++)
{
total += *ptr;

ptr++;

}
printf("\n\n\n\t\tTHE NEURON IS: %.2f", total);

}
```

Comment: `for(input; input<11; input++)` --> `for(input=0; input<10; input++)`

Comment: can you please clearly explain what you meant*

Comment: `11` --> `10` : index does not include the 10, `input` is required to be reset.

Comment: Also as you don't initialise on the second iteration, which does the addition, input is already not less than 11 and therefore there's no iteration of the loop!

Comment: can you help me if you don't mind. now i'm stuck with this part, from your correction i've to get the sum of all the entered numbers multiply by their generated ones.

Comment: when i'm adding this in the first for loop it rejects it               printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tMachine Value: %.1f", generatedNum);
  
  ptr = number * generatedNum;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier solution is to simply keep everything in one loop. There really isn't a need for a pointer in this situation as nothing requires them, add the values as you get them. Also you never use the generatedNum (although maybe this is for further development??)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void application(void)
    {
    int input = 0;
    float number[10];
    float total =0;
    float generatedNum; 

    srand(time(NULL));


    for(; input<10; input++)
    {   
        generatedNum = 2 *(float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX - 1;


        printf("\n\n\t\tEnter number %d : ", input);
        scanf("%f", &number[input]);
        total += number[input];

        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tMachine Value: %.1f", generatedNum);
    }    
    printf("\n\n\n\t\tTHE NEURON IS: %.2f", total);
    return;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    application();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you help me if you don't mind. now i'm stuck with this part, from your correction i've to get the sum of all the entered numbers multiply by their generated ones.

Comment: when i'm adding this in the first for loop it rejects it printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tMachine Value: %.1f", generatedNum); ptr = number * generatedNum;

Comment: It sounds like you will want a separate array to either store the generated values or the product of the two values. Depending on the approach you can turn generatedNum into an array (float generatedNum[10]) and simple do generatedNum[input] = 2 *(float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX - 1; or you can store the product in an array generatedProduct[input] = number[input] * generatedNum. Which route you take depends on if you'll need to use the generated numbers in future calculations.

Comment: if you don't mind can you put it in the code that i've posted? i try to do this but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void application(void)
{
    int input = 0;
    float number[10];
    float total =0;
    float *ptr;
    float generatedNum; 

    srand(time(NULL));


    for(; input<10; input++)
    {   
        generatedNum = 2 *(float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX - 1;


        printf("\n\n\t\tEnter number %d : ", input);
        scanf("%f", &number[input]);
        ptr = number;

        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tMachine Value: %.1f", generatedNum);

    }

    for(input = 0; input<10; input++)
    {
        total += *ptr;

        ptr++;

    }
    printf("\n\n\n\t\tTHE NEURON IS: %.2f", total);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    application();

    return 0;
}
```

your array will get out of bound if you go for `< 11` because it might contain 10 position but it's starting at 0.

Also the first loop manipulates your `input` variable which is then higher than the required condition of your second loop.
So you need to set it back to 0.

[Working example!](http://ideone.com/xkNJTf)

Comment: can you help me if you don't mind. now i'm stuck with this part, from your correction i've to get the sum of all the entered numbers multiply by their generated ones.

Comment: when i'm adding this in the first for loop it rejects it               printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tMachine Value: %.1f", generatedNum);
  
  ptr = number * generatedNum;